# SSH alternative for a long range/high latency connection

Tags: ssh, remote-access, ssh-tunnel

I'm about to set-up a raspberrypi in a remote location (300+km to me). It will connect via GSM since there's no landline on 3G/4G. I need a way to "ssh" inside the pi to manage some stuff. Since GSM has no port forwarding my idea was to use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to tunnel the shell connection.

The only problem is that SSH is too heavy to run on a 600+ms connection. Mosh seems good and robust but I need to set a static key and port and I don't know if it's possible.

Telnet is also an option since ngrok encrypts the tunnels. Any alternative? I also need to upload/download some small files (x/zmodem?)

Answer (score 5):

mosh (Mobile Shell) is what you are looking for, though you need it on both client and server side...

https://mosh.mit.edu

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to forget for a moment that you're using a RPi for this and are instead using a reliable, professional-grade piece of hardware.

1. Use IPSec or some other VPN to tunnel traffic back to your main location. It this isn't an option, use autossh with a reverse port forward to maintain a persistent connection.
2. Use Ansible to manage the remote system. It does use SSH, but it's not interactive, so it doesn't matter if it takes 30 seconds or 5 minutes to complete its tasks. You can develop and test your Ansible playbooks against a local target to verify they're doing what you expect before applying them to the remote system.
3. Make sure you have compression enabled in SSH.

Comment: I'm struggling to imagine where such an architecture makes any sense, never mind for across a low bandwidth/high latency connection.

Comment: Why *wouldn't* it make sense? What part of it? I've implemented this exact thing many times for access to poorly-connected systems with great success.

Comment: The RPI ha a fallback AVR that manages power and network, it's for a school project, we don't have a big budget.

Answer (score 1):

you can use ssh over a connection with hundreds of milliseconds of latency. It can be frustrating but it's not impossible.

Mosh normally uses ssh to set up the intial connection, high latency should not be a problem for this. You will however need to make sure the UDP port mosh needs gets through.

My advice would be rather than messing around with individual ports to use openvpn to set up a VPN from your remote device back to your own network. Then use ssh/mosh with internal IPs. You might want to consider setting up a watchdog script on the pi to test the VPN and restart it if needed. Cellular networks can be pretty shaky at times.

Answer (score 0):

My solutions are slightly out-of-the-box.

First, try to figure out if you can get at least 3G if not LTE, but 3G already should give you enough throughput to use ssh easily for medium weight tasks. Depending on what modem you have, there is a range of aerials characterised by power gain. Try to get a good map of mobile network coverage and find the nearest base station. For this you need to take into consideration the radio propagation rules. *The nearest one* may be not the one that is at the shortest distance, but the the one which has an aerial sector facing you with the largest power. With a dash of reading and calculations, you may get a satisfactory cellular link.

The second solution is similar, but it's not about the mobile notworks, but the wifi hotspots. People often are not aware of the radio internet providers in their area. If you are able to survey the air with a strong aearial, why not try that. If not a commercial ISP, there may be a free hotspot in a town nearby. Or you may have a good neighbour round with a good net connection, who you think lives too far.

In both of the solutions, the quality of aerials and modem / network card is important. No less are the cables and connectors.

Comment: No wifi points in a 10km range. 3G and 4G are available in the area but the quality is very low, GSM always work (mostly). I was trinking about a radio uplink, but I need to setup this pi in a forest, and unfortunately there is a Military base very close to my station so I need to ask a lot of permissions.

Comment: I don't know what country that is, but aerials for 3G/4G seem to me most plain civilian infrastructure. The army will find out easily if you start tempering with the regions of air you shouldn't. They shouldn't mind anything going on in the mobile network bands, which are strictly defined.

Comment: As for wifi, 10 years ago I collected networks from about slightly less than your distance away. And that was in the city centre. Today the equipment is better, and the interference in the forrest is much lower. You will want to have the other aearial in your aearial's line of sight. A tall tree may be an idea. The bottle neck in a simple configuration is the low amperage from Raspberry Pi's USB socket. You will need some sort of hub with its own power or a pc slot card connected to the Pi somehow. Anyhow, do your own calculations if this all makes sense, as I may be wrong.

Comment: An access point compliant with either 802.11b or 802.11g, using the stock antenna might have a range of 100 m (330 ft). The same radio with an external semi parabolic antenna (15 dB gain) might have a range over 20 miles. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi#Range

Comment: Italy, but I was talking about the Radio uplink (UHF). Power is a non-issue, the pi is powered by an external power regulator (12v --> 5v, 6A max) since this whole thing is solar and battery powered. I could just solder the GND and 5V usb pin to the regulator and leaving the D+ D- on the usb socket. In a couple of days we should go to this location, I will make some tests.

Comment: I'm not that good with soldering and stuff, but I know for sure you will need more power on the aerial cable than Pi can give you as it is. Propagation-wise, you may find problems with meeting the wifi aearial face-to-face. It may be pointed more at the town buildings. But you may be lucky too. The mobile network aerials may be pointed at the forrest on purpose. However, the operator might have designated just the GSM in this direction. At the end you may also be interested in making the GSM reception strong and stable. If the signal is about ok, any better wire should do.

Comment: If you go for LTE, you will need 2 aerials.